# Devise model not calling after_rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When you are trying to register through Devise and you get a validation error, `after_rollback` is not called on the user model. This makes [validation_auditor](https://github.com/pupeno/validation_auditor) not record the validation error.

I'm the author of validation_auditor, so [I added a test](https://github.com/pupeno/validation_auditor/blob/master/test/model_test.rb#L14-L37) to see if calling save on a new record, which [is what Devise is doing](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L17) and my test passes just fine.

Any ideas why when Devise is saving a user model, it might not be calling after_rollback?